# Sql query not executing - showing invalid identifier error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
with ticket_orders AS(
    select REGEXP_SUBSTR(st.ORDER_ID, '\d{3}-\d{7}-\d{7}') "new_order_id"

from

(select 

REGEXP_SUBSTR(details, 'Order\s+ID(\s*\(s\))?:\s*\d{3}-\d{7}-\d{7}') AS "ORDER_ID" 
from o_remedy ort
) st)


select new_t.new_order_id from ticket_orders new_t;
```

I'm trying to execute the following sql statement but it keeps showing error as `"NEW_T"."NEW_ORDER_ID": invalid identifier`

How to get this "`new_order_id`" because I need to join it further.

Comment: Don't you mean "the preceding SQL statement"?

Comment: You are selecting `t.new_order_id` but the error is showing as `"NEW_T"."NEW_ORDER_ID"` ? Where does `NEW_T` comes from?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped it is new_t only

Comment: @toonice What do you mean "preceding SQL statement"?

Comment: You said "the following sql statement" about an SQL statement that had gone before that sentence.  "Preceding" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Either remove double quotes from the derived column name, or use double quotes in select clause as well.

```
select new_t."new_order_id" from ticket_orders new_t;
```

By default, Oracle convert every object name to upper case, unless you specify it in double quotes. So `"new_order_id"` will not be converted to upper case, but while selecting `new_t.new_order_id` will be converted to upper case, which doesn't exist.

To resolve it, either remove double quotes from the derived column name, or use double quotes in select clause as well.

I replicated it like this on my local machine.

This will not work.

```
with tbl as 
(select empno "new_emp_no" from emp)
select t.new_emp_no From tbl t
```

And give

> ORA-00904: "T"."NEW_EMP_NO": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 116 Column: 10

But this will work.

```
with tbl as 
(select empno "new_emp_no" from emp)
select t."new_emp_no" From tbl t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH ticket_orders AS
(
    SELECT 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(st.ORDER_ID, '\d{3}-\d{7}-\d{7}') new_order_id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(details, 'Order\s+ID(\s*\(s\))?:\s*\d{3}-\d{7}-\d{7}') AS ORDER_ID 
        FROM o_remedy ort
    )  st
)
SELECT new_t.new_order_id FROM ticket_orders new_t;
```